# SVN ignores file

Tags: svn, xcode

I added another XCode Project file into my repository using "svn add"

But the problem is that when I want to check out the repository the added .xcodeproj package is empty and I get an error from XCode - cannot find .pbxproj file.

I'm sure that I don't have "*.pbxproj" set in my global igonres.

Why doesn't SVN add files included in the package?
How can I make SVN add .pbxproj files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a filter up for files with an extension like that. You can just check your svn settings and see if you have any active filters running.

Comment: Do I have to check this in .subversion/config file?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what type of subversion you are using. Normally i guess every subversion client has an option to set filters.